# Classes in C++ what is this function asking me to do

Tags: c++, function, class

Here is the description of te function I am supposed to develop...give
a
Money
instance
that
rounds
the
monetary
amount
to
the
nearest
coin
(e.g.
NICKEL).
In
everyday
language
we
would
say
that
this
method
(function)
gives
back
change;
however,
it
does
not
change
the
calling
object
itself
but
rather,
returns
a
new
instance.
This
function
would
be
used
in
retail
in
Canada
to
give
back
a
monetary
amount
as
change
in
coins.

So I understand the return type will be a new instance aka object of Money and the parameters should be a money instance, but what else  is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Can you give us some more context? For instance, are you given a spec or class definition for `class Money`?

Comment: From the context I can read that this function/class already exist and needs some improvements/fixes. Maybe post some code ? `In everyday language we would say that this method (function) gives back change; however, it does not change the calling object itself but rather, returns a new instance.`